# I am coding to find average marks & grades with python. However, the process didn't work as I expected cuz I am not sure where I made mistakes

Tags: python, function

```
    marks = input("Tell me what marks you got? ")
    marks = list(marks.split(","))

#This split is to remove comma while users input comma

    def find_average_marks(marks):
        sum_of_marks = sum(marks)
        total_subjects = len(marks)
        average_marks = sum_of_marks/total_subjects
        return average_marks

    print(marks)
    average_marks = find_average_marks(marks)
    print("Your average mark is: ", average_marks)

#I also want to know how to work with def too.
```

it didn't come out as I expected cuz there are some errors. I hope this solve with the help of ur guys.

Comment: "the process didn't work as I expected" - how did you expect it to work? How is it working instead? The likely issue is that you're having the user enter a string (`str`) and you split it up into a list of strings, but you can't `sum()` strings - you need to interpret those strings as integers first (with `int()`)

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments. I will be careful with those integer types in the future. Thanks for reminding me like this!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`marks = [int(x) for x in marks]`

Add this line below `marks = list(...)`

The mistake you had in your code was that you did not convert your input into numbers and then you got an error when you tried to sum up strings :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I will be careful with those integers type. It helps and it works now. Once again, thanks a lot!!!